# How to get a kendo grid on a kendo template

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window, kendo-template

Firstly I have made a Kendo grid. Each row of the grid has a button on it, which on-click opens a Kendo template (pop-up). still here it's fine.

**Is it possible to add another grid in the popup** and add editable child items(*like grid hierarchy*) to each grid row?

**This is my main grid:**

```js
var grid= $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
          { field: "Name", title: "Name" },
          { field: "Description", title:"Description"},
          { field: "Remarks", title:"Remarks" },
          { command: { name: "details", text: "....", click: showDetails }, title: "Button", attributes: {
              style: "text-align: center;"
          }
          },
          {field:"Status",title:"Status"},
          ],


{......... data source and irrelevant code }

});
```

**Code for window pop-up and button on-click function:**

```js
wnd = $("#details")
                        .kendoWindow({
                            title: "Details",
                            modal: true,
                            visible: false,
                            resizable: false,
                            width: 400,
                            height:600
                        }).data("kendoWindow");

    detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
    });

    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
        wnd.center().open();
    }
```

**Code for template look like:**

```js
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">

    <div id="details-container">
        
        <dl>
            <dt id="fac">Fan: </dt>
            <dt id="gc"> AC </dt>
            <dt id="pn"> Name: </dt>
            <dt id=pk> #=Name# </dt>
            <dt id="sn">Status: </dt>
            <dt id=sk> #=Status# </dt>

        </dl>
        <br />
        <div class="rowdiv">
   
            <div id="windowgrid"></div>
           <!-- windowgrid is another grid which I need to get from this template, it is not displaying the grid but give a space in between -->         
           
        </div>
   
        <br />
        <button id="bbb3" class="button">Cancel</button>
        <button id="bbb2" class="button">Save</button>
        <button id="bbb1" class="button">Refresh </button>



    </div>
</script>
```

The div tag including window grid is not displaying the grid but displaying remaining other things.
can you suggest what mistake I have done in the code
Secondly, Can you help me with the code to get a child row for each grid row.

Thank you

**EDIT** This is the dojo link of whole code: http://dojo.telerik.com/igOroG

Comment: Consider adding a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/) to accommodate your question and demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Can you go through the code in the given dojo link and explain why a 2nd grid is not being displayed in template pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialise an element before it has been rendered in the `x-kendo-template`, so just move your grid instantiation to after the `open` of the `kendoWindow`.

```
function showDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
    // grid definition here
    var grid = $("#windowgrid").kendoGrid({
        .....
    }).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

*"Code to get a child row for each grid row"*

You can use [`detailInit`](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate) with `detailTemplate` on the grids in order to achieve this. With your `detailInit` function, you will be able to access the data at that specific row using `[e.data]`.

```
// gets elements on detailRow
var detailRow = e.detailRow;
// get the data at the expanded row
var dataList = [e.data];
```

I have updated your [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/igOroG/3) to display the changes required to firstly initialise the grid and extended the code to provide detail rows for the first grid.

### EDIT

In order to apply a filtered dataSource to the pop-up grid based on the value selected, you can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function on the data before applying to the Kendo DataSource:

```
var filteredDataArr = dataArr.filter(function(el) {
    return el.NId == e.NId      
});
```

`el` being the element in the data array and `e.NId` being the selected `NId` in the parent grid.

Updated [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/11) to demonstrate the above in action.

Comment: Thank you,Now everything is working fine.
The example you showed has a single column in the child row.
But what should I do to get two columns in the child row?

Comment: If you wish to add additional information, it's just a case of extending the `x-kendo-template` to add more `<div>` elements for whatever you need. If you would like to use a nested grid, there is an example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy). In your case, if using local data, you can simply bind the `dataSource` of that grid element to the `dataList` extracted for the parent row.

Comment: Right now I have converted everything into Angular-JS. http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/3 you can look that here, there is again a problem with the grid inside the pop-up window, this time in a different way. I have explained it in comments inside the pop-up grid dataSource, please go through it.

Comment: You had incorrectly assigned the kendo dataSource, you specified `data` as `Cdata`; this would cause the pop-up grid not to be populated - see [updated Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/5)

Comment: Thanks, Is there a chance that I click the button on row 1 under class column and I get the grid with only those 4 rows having NId='1'

Comment: @SrikarKrishna I updated my answer to include a method to filter the dataSource used in the pop-up grid

Comment: Yeah but I haven't got the full answer. I've updated it as a new question. can you please go through this. [Updated Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545719/how-to-get-a-different-grid-as-child-from-a-different-row-of-another-grid-using)