# How to get a different grid as child from a different row of another grid using Kendo detailInit function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have made a grid with buttons in each row which on-click opens a pop-up having different grids on each button.

Each row of the pop-up grid may have a child (another grid with only one column). And if there is no child it should be empty.

So, I'm trying to map each row with a child using parent-Id(PId) and (Id) as shown in the given example, which is taking all the available child's into a row or taking none of them into it.

[Dojo Sample Code](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/17)

Comment: can you describe the functional issue? "When I do X, this happens, but this is what I want to happen"

Comment: Can you go through the detailInit function and dataSource of pop-up grid?
When I click on the button in first row, I get a pop-up with 2 columns, where 1st row is having child item and even 2nd row is having it, which shouldn't be there. mapping of row and child should be done using parentId and Id

Comment: What condition needs to be met in order for their to be a nested row item?

Comment: There should be a dataItem with the PId equal to that of ID of the parent row. Else it won't have any child row item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `detailInit` requires a slightly different method of exposing the data belonging to the parent item.  You can extract this data using `e.data` like so:

```
var newData2 = crdata.filter(function(ell) {
    return ell.NId == e.data.Id && ell.PId != 0;     
});
```

That along with checking that the dataSource NId = parent row Id and moving the setup of the dataSource for the child grid into the `detailInit` function itself should do the trick.

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/28) to demonstrate the above.

Comment: But my 2nd row item don't have any child? why does it show there?

Comment: [dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ivEYA/29) check with this data, that isn't working but made the previous one wrong too.

Comment: If you want to remove the functionality from being able to drop down altogether, you could [use the `dataBound` event to validate the data as it is being populated - and hide the detail grid arrow indicator where required](http://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-detail-indicator-detail-grid#quJfW5EaHEitfrdhjlJNQg).